How to delete oldest row sql using sequelize. subquery
I try to delete just oldest row in table so sql gonna be like this.
DELETE FROM `session` WHERE `id` IN (
  SELECT `id`
  FROM `session`
  WHERE `userId` = :id
  ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC
  LIMIT 1
)

But using sequelize it will look like this.
const foundToken = await SessionModel.findOne({
  attributes: ["id"],
    where: {
      userId: foundUser.id,
    },
    order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
  })
  if (foundToken)
    await SessionModel.destroy({
      where: {
    id: foundToken.id,
  },
})

So how can I make it better then this?
Using Signal instance with subquery.

Could you try this?
if (foundToken) await foundToken.destroy();


Why ORDER BY `createdAt` DESC LIMIT 1? This code selects the most recent row. If you need in the oldest one then you must use ASC. 2) Why not simply DELETE FROM session WHERE userId = :id ORDER BY createdAt ASC LIMIT 1;? Does id is not primary key column?


Yes, PK column is id. But no, can't order by id because id is not auto increment. My db use uuid at PK instance.

Where you have read about sorting by id?

You can use Sequelize.where and Sequelize.literal in static destroy method to imitate the subquery from that raw SQL query
